# How do I access local web pages on the Android?

Tags: android

I have some web pages that I want to bundle with my Android application and display as static pages.  Where do I put them?  How do I access them?  I'm working in Eclipse, so I want a solution that automatically bundles them.

I've tried putting my web pages in res/raw, and I can read them as an input stream from there, so I could push that into a WebView.  But I'd really prefer if I could stick them somewhere and access them with a URL.  I've tried file:///android_asset/about.html but that didn't work.  Surely there's a way to form a URL to display bundled pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put them into the "assets" folder and do:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```